Cannot seem to parse dates correctly in spark 3
I'm trying to write a utilitary that "evaluates" the well formatting of dates. I cannot seem to suceed in this because I keep getting errors like :
Exception has occurred: Py4JJavaError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
An error occurred while calling o184.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) (172.21.66.190 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
Fail to parse '2023-10-15 13:45:30' in the new parser. You can set "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy" to "LEGACY" to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to "CORRECTED" and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
Fail to parse '2023-10-15 13:45:30' in the new parser. You can set "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy" to "LEGACY" to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to "CORRECTED" and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
...
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-10-15T13:45:30' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1874)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.parse(TimestampFormatter.scala:193)
        ... 21 more

Here's a minimal script of what i'm trying to recreaate the error
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, col, coalesce

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateParsingTest").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

# Sample data for testing
data = [
    ("2023-10-15T13:45:30",),
    ("2023-10-15 13:45:30",),
    ("2023-10-15",),
    ("20231015",),
    ("15-Oct-2023",),
    ("10/15/2023",),
    ("15/10/2023",),
    ("2023.10.15",),
    ("Oct 15, 2023",),
    ("15 Oct 2023",),
    ("2023/10/15",),
    ("15-10-2023",),
    ("10-15-2023",),
    ("15.10.2023",),
    ("10.15.2023",),
    ("InvalidDate",),
    (None,),
]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["date_string"])

# Define date formats
date_formats = [
    "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "yyyyMMdd",
    "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "dd-MMM-yyyy",
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "yyyy.MM.dd",
    "MMM dd, yyyy",
    "dd MMM yyyy",
    "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "MM-dd-yyyy",
    "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "MM.dd.yyyy",
]

# Define time formats to append
time_formats = [
    "",  # No time
    " HH:mm:ss",
    " HH:mm:ss.SSS",
    "'T'HH:mm:ss",
    "'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
]


# Generate combined date-time formats
date_time_formats = []
for date_fmt in date_formats:
    for time_fmt in time_formats:
        date_time_formats.append(date_fmt + time_fmt)


# Parse the date strings
parsing_expressions = [to_timestamp(col("date_string"), fmt) for fmt in date_time_formats]

# Use coalesce to get the first successfully parsed timestamp
parsed_date_expr = coalesce(*parsing_expressions)

# Add the parsed date column to the DataFrame
df = df.withColumn("parsed_date", parsed_date_expr)

# Show the results
df.select("date_string", "parsed_date").show(truncate=False)

# Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()


The goal of this module is to evaluate date time strings in data so that we may fix them when necessary. These columns often have heterogenous date time formats.
I found this question with a similar premise, but the answers within it did not fix my problem.
Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

I seem to have found the problem :
the method to_timestamp expects a datetime format, the problem is with the time format "",  # No time in this collection :
time_formats = [
    "",  # No time
    " HH:mm:ss",
    " HH:mm:ss.SSS",
    "'T'HH:mm:ss",
    "'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
]

In order to fix acceptable datetime formats for to_timestamp, use brackets [..] to denote optional time for the relevant formats. For example :
# Define date formats
date_formats = [
    "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "yyyyMMdd",
    "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "dd-MMM-yyyy",
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "yyyy.MM.dd",
    "MMM dd, yyyy",
    "dd MMM yyyy",
    "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "MM-dd-yyyy",
    "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "MM.dd.yyyy",
]

# Define time formats to append
time_formats = [
    "[ HH:mm:ss]",
    "['T'HH:mm:ss]",
    "[ HH:mm:ss.SSS]",
    "['T'HH:mm:ss.SSS]",
]

This renders all the time formats optional, and so the parsing works :
+-------------------+-------------------+                                       
|date_string        |parsed_date        |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2023-10-15T13:45:30|2023-10-15 13:45:30|
|2023-10-15 13:45:30|2023-10-15 13:45:30|
|2023-10-15         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|20231015           |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|15-Oct-2023        |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|10/15/2023         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|15/10/2023         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|2023.10.15         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|Oct 15, 2023       |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|15 Oct 2023        |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|2023/10/15         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|15-10-2023         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|10-15-2023         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|15.10.2023         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|10.15.2023         |2023-10-15 00:00:00|
|InvalidDate        |NULL               |
|NULL               |NULL               |
+-------------------+-------------------+

